# Form action now points to 'r.ashx' with MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7, iis-7

All of a sudden my form link looks like this:

```
<form action="/r.ashx/Models.Module_ContactUs?action=Submit&amp;controller=Contact" id="contactUsForm" method="post">
```

This was working before but it appears something has changed with IIS.

Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactUsForm" }))
{
    <div class="contact-form">
        <h4><strong>Send Us a Message</strong></h4>
            <div class="form-row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Form.Name, "Your Name *")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Form.Name, new { tabindex = 1, @class = "field blink" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Form.Name, "First name required.")
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Form.Name, "Your Email *")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Form.Email, new { tabindex = 2, @class = "field blink" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Form.Email, "")
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Form.Name, "Subject *")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Form.Subject, new { tabindex = 3, @class = "field blink" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Form.Subject, "Subject required.")
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Form.Message, "Your Message *")
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Form.Message, new { tabindex = 4, @class = "field blink" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Form.Message, "Message required.")
            </div>
            <div class="form-buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="submit-button" id="SubmtButton" tabindex="5" />
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("BlogArchive", "Blog/{year}/{month}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "FilterByMonth" }, new { year = @"\d+", month = @"\d+" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogRedirect", "Blog/Redirect", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Redirect" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogListingFiltered", "Blog/{filterBy}/{filter}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Filter" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogCategories", "Blog/Category/{categoryFriendlyName}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "FilterByCategory" });

            // 404 page...
            routes.MapRoute("Errors", "Errors/{action}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" });

            // Error Pages
            routes.MapRoute("Error", "Errors/{errorCode}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error", errorCode = UrlParameter.Optional });

            // Agility Builtin Route
            routes.MapRoute("Agility", "{*sitemapPath}", new { controller = "Agility", action = "RenderPage" });

            // needs to be here, after agility routing for url generation to happen
            routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact/{action}", new { controller = "Contact", action = "Submit" });

            //default method for action/controller
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error", id = "" });
        }
```

Web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
      <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET,POST" type="Glimpse.Core.Handler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Module" />
    </httpModules>
```

Comment: What are the Routes defined in your MVC Project?

Comment: off the top of my head it looks like a routing issue. It might be more helpful to see what your Global.ashx file looks like.

Comment: Do you have an httpmodules or httphandlers on this project?

Comment: updated post with piece of code from the web.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this line of code to RegisterRoutes in the global.asax resolved the issue:

```
routes.Clear();
```

Comment: If someone adds a better answer which helps you understand *why* you might want to re-add the bounty.